# Code Build Failed with error at "Download_Source: A stunnel process is required for curated image EFS builds and it did not start: exit status 127"

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-codebuild, amazon-efs, aws-devops

I have configured code build environment with ***aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:corretto8*** and also trying to store the cache in my EFS by configuring it in code build environment File System but my build got failed with error: "A stunnel process is required for curated image EFS builds and it did not start: exit status 127".
Earlier I was using the image: ***aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0* **then build were working fine, but as aws come up with the new image ***aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:corretto8*** and removed the ***standar:3.0***. my builds are failing, now I cannot revert back to *standard 3.0* as it is removed from the image list.
I appreciate your help on this,
Thanks

Goal: successful build